# Adding borders based on grouped rows and conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that looks like this:

[image: Image 1]

As you can see, it is a simple inventory tracking system. Right now, I have 3 products. Some products don't really have different colors (like Tacky Design Tee), so for those, the variant (color) is kept empty. One issue I faced is that it gets a bit difficult to actually understand which row I'm in because some cells are kept empty. Ideally, I would want the spreadsheet to look like this:

[image: Image 2]

With the borders, there is a clear separation between the products. I want this to be dynamic. The logic might come from the `B` column not being empty, and all the rows right after it where `B` is empty, those rows are treated as a group and bordered on the bottom.

Is there a way to do this in a way so that whenever I add a new product, it gets grouped accordingly? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

Links to the spreadsheets:

Before (What I have):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3ybiy5Gaw7SYDZlYA68HmvPCCoxI-Bz7qpPCSK146A/edit?usp=sharing

After (Basically what I want):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sS3Y_MH4DaYD4QW19vjwExd7jc4H-eB5OAGb3J4njUQ/edit?usp=sharing

In short, I want to group products based on their names based on these 2 conditions:

- If a row does not have a name, we assume it to be a variant of the closest row going up that has a product name.
- If two rows have the same product name, we obviously assume them to be variants of the same product.

Comment: I think that OnEdit event trigger can be used for dynamically adding the borders. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet you want to use? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike I added links to the spreadsheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying and sharing the sample Spreadsheets. By these samples, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample script? In this sample script, when you edit a cell in the sheet of "Sheet1", the border is dynamically added by the OnEdit event trigger. Please think of this as just one of several answers. The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Script is automatically run by OnEdit event trigger, when the cell is edited.
2. Retrieve the sheet name.
3. Clear all borders.
4. Create a range list for adding the border.
5. Add the border using the range list.

I used above flow, because I'm not sure about the situation of editing cells.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of the Spreadsheet (in this case, please do this to "Before" Spreadsheet.). When you edit a cell, the border is added.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Sheet1") {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).setBorder(null, null, null, null, false, false);
    var values = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
    var rangeList = values.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
      if (i > 0 && values[i - 1][0] != e[0] && e[0] != "") {
        ar.push("A" + (i + 1) + ":D" + (i + 1));
      }
      return ar;
    }, [])
    rangeList.push(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation());
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, when the edited sheet name is "Sheet1", the script is run. If you want to modify this, please modify `if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Sheet1") {`.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [setBorder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop-left-bottom-right-vertical-horizontal-color-style)

### Edit:

- Your 1st shared Spreadsheet is different from your actual Spreadsheet.

  - The shared Spreadsheet in your reply comment is the actual Spreadsheet.
- You want to check the column "C" and add the border from the column "A" to "P".
- Data starts from row 3.

If my understanding is correct, please modify above script as follows.

#### From:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(3, 3, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
```

And

#### From:

```
if (i > 0 && values[i - 1][0] != e[0] && e[0] != "") {
  ar.push("A" + (i + 1) + ":D" + (i + 1));
}
```

#### To:

```
if (i > 0 && values[i - 1][0] != e[0] && e[0] != "") {
  ar.push("A" + (i + 2) + ":P" + (i + 2));
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bring this up after accepting the answer, however, the code formats the table a bit differently in my actual spreadsheet (not the sample). My actual spreadsheet looks like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zoWuclQLMzoL9PsQHS7lvT7aqtDhSgZw1QfVHXcvO18/edit?usp=sharing. Columns go upto P, product name starts from C, and the 3rd row marks the start of the actual data. What changes do I need to make to your script?

Comment: @darkhorse I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood about your actual Spreadsheet, I apologize.

Comment: Works amazingly well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note: Shifting the line of code that sets all the borders to null initially to right before the line that adds the new borders removes all the lag from the point of view of the user. It feels almost instant.

Comment: @darkhorse You moved ``sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).setBorder(null, null, null, null, false, false)`` from after ``var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();`` to after ``}, [])``. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes thats exactly right. Rendering before all the loops and calculations produced a visible delay where the borders vanished for a second and re-appeared again.

Comment: @darkhorse I could understand about it. The disappearance time can be shorter by adding the borders just after they are cleared. Thank you for the additional information.

Comment: @TheMaster If you have any questions and discussions, feel free to tell me. I always welcome to discuss.