# How to remove actions taken by onEdit trigger from the undo history list in Google Sheets and App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In one of my sheets, I'm using a simple script to change the borders of some cells on every edit.

It kinda looks like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    ...
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).setBorder(null, null, null, null, false, false);
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "#BBDEFB", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
  }
}
```

Everything works nicely, however, after editing something, lets say I press CMD+Z (or CTRL+Z) to undo my last action. What actually happens is that the border that was added gets removed, because technically that was the last action.

Is there a well known solution to problems of this nature?

Edit:
I created a manual trigger function based on the first answer. However, Google Sheets has a limit of one trigger per user per spreadsheet. So the borders were changed only once. I also deleted the trigger as it said so, and even then it did not work.

**Moreover, is there a better way to do this? Setting the borders to null on every edit basically makes it impossible to add custom borders at all.**

Comment: `Google Sheets has a limit of one trigger per user per spreadsheet.` Not true

Answer (score 2):

- You don't want to remove the added border by the script, when the keys of CMD+Z (or CTRL+Z) was pressed.
- Your base script is used at [Adding borders based on grouped rows and conditional formatting in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55943889/7108653).

If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? Please think of this as just one of several workarounds.

When the Spreadsheet is modified from outside, even if the keys of CMD+Z (or CTRL+Z) was pressed, the modified action cannot be canceled. In this workaround, I used this.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, **please install the function of `sample()` as OnEdit event trigger.** By this, when you edit a cell, the function of `sample()` is automatically run. You can see how to install the trigger at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

```
function sample(e) {
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Sheet1") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.source.getId()).getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Modified
    var values = sheet.getRange(3, 3, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
    var rangeList = values.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
      if (i > 0 && (values[i - 1][0] != e[0] && e[0] != "")) {
        ar.push("A" + (i + 2) + ":P" + (i + 2));
      }
      return ar;
    }, [])
    rangeList.push(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation());
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).setBorder(null, null, null, null, false, false);
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- When you use this script, please rename the function of `onEdit(e)` to other name like `onEdit_sample(e)`. Because there is `onEdit()` in the script, both `sample()` installed as the OnEdit trigger and `onEdit()` are run. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

### Edit:

By your additional request, I added a sample script for installing the OnEdit event trigger for the function of `sample()`.

#### Sample script:

```
var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("sample").forSpreadsheet(id).onEdit().create();
```

Comment: Could you please include the trigger installation code as well?

Comment: @darkhorse Thank you for replying. And I apologize for the inconvenience. For your additional request, I added a sample script for installing the OnEdit event trigger for the function of ``sample()``. Could you please confirm it? When you run the script one time, the event trigger is installed. If I misunderstood your additional request, I apologize.

Comment: Unfortunately, the trigger limit is set to one per user per spreadsheet. The code worked only once, but no borders were set after that. I also deleted the trigger, but it still did not help with the limit.

Comment: @darkhorse I apologize for the inconvenience. When the OnEdit event trigger was installed, the script is run as owner. So when you who are owner of Spreadsheet installed the OnEdit event trigger, the trigger works for other users. For example, the following situation is supposed. 1. Spreadsheet that you are an owner is shared with other users. 2. The script is set as the container-bound script. 3. You install the OnEdit event trigger for the function of ``sample``.

Comment: @darkhorse In above situation, when other users edit the cells, the script is automatically run by the OnEdit trigger. If the trigger didn't work even if you did above, can you provide the detail information about the flow for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to think of your issue.

Comment: @darkhorse By the way, unfortunately, I couldn't understand about ``Google Sheets has a limit of one trigger per user per spreadsheet.``. Can I ask you about this? I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @darkhorse I apologize for the inconvenience. As an additional information, I could confirm that when an user who is other account edits the cell of the shared Spreadsheet which installed the OnEdit event trigger and the script, the script worked fine, now. So If my understanding for your situation is correct, I think that in your environment, the OnEdit trigger can be used. Could you please confirm about this again?

Comment: Basically what happened was this: the script worked only once. After that, it stopped working. The error shown was something along the lines of "Too many triggers. Delete some to make room." I could not fix that issue.

Comment: @darkhorse Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor skill. From your initial question, I couldn't understand why you installed a lot of triggers. I apologize for my poor English skill. In my answer, the trigger is installed only one time by owner. By this, other users can the script. So as a test, can you remove all triggers related to above script and install the trigger only one time and can you try it again? And also, please check whether function of ``onEdit()`` is not existing in your script.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need instant formatting changes, could try setting up a time-based trigger [programatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) to run every X number of minutes.

Creating custom Sheet menu options to turn this automatic monitoring On / Off may be of interest.