# Google sheets auto sort script modification to trigger only on specified column change

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, multiple-columns

I have this auto sort script and it works great but I can't figure out how to change two things.

Instead of the script being triggered by every change in the entire sheet I'd like it to trigger when only two specific columns are edited (C and D).

```
SHEET_NAME = "North Tonawanda";
 SORT_DATA_RANGE = "C:D";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 4, ascending: true} // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort Completed.');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

I would rewrite the script as follows. This makes it visually clearer and the `onEdit` trigger uses the `SORT_ORDER` variable to see the columns that trigger the function:

### Code

```
SHEET_NAME = "North Tonawanda";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "C:D";
SORT_ORDER = [
  { column: 3, ascending: true },
  { column: 4, ascending: true }
];


function multiSortColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort Completed.');
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet().getName()
  var columnStart = e.range.columnStart
  var columnEnd = e.range.columnEnd

  if (SHEET_NAME == editedSheet
    && columnStart >= SORT_ORDER[0]["column"]
    && columnEnd <= SORT_ORDER[1]["column"]) {
    multiSortColumns() 
  }
}
```

### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Yeah that is much cleaner and it worked perfectly. I ended up getting rid of the onEdit and adding it to the menu to be done manually but now I'll be using it on a different tab. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From your question and your script, you want to run the function of `multiSortColumns()` when the columns "C" and "D" of the sheet `North Tonawanda` are edited.

In this case, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using the event object. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
```

To:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() != SHEET_NAME || (range.columnStart != 3 && range.columnStart != 4)) return;
  multiSortColumns();
}
```

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: I modified it and the script still works but I tried editing a random cell and then checked the Executions and it still logged the trigger. I tried cells before and after the specified columns. Also the little white box confirmation still pops up at the bottom of the sheet for every change,,

Comment: @Yianni V Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my proposed script, `multiSortColumns` is run when the columns "C" and "D" of the sheet "North Tonawanda" are edited. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script? By this, I would like to confirm it. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Yianni V By the way, in this case, when the cell is edited, the log shows the simple trigger. And your `multiSortColumns` is run in `onEdit` when the if statement is `false`. But, I cannot replicate `Also the little white box confirmation still pops up at the bottom of the sheet for every change`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Yianni V From [your this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66618605), when you test my proposed script in [this sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nP4kZEikx1li8JNwCjsEc3ooadr0fiboglUizUcUdAQ/edit?usp=sharing), I think that my proposed script might not correctly work. I'm worry about this.

Comment: @Yianni V Because when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the function with the function name of `onEdit` is used in each your container-bound script. In this case, your script is not correctly run. Those `onEdit` functions are run with the asynchronous process. So when you test the script of `onEdit`, please rename other `onEdit` functions except for the function `onEdit` you want to test. Please be careful this.